# Date field regular expression

Tags: php, regex, validation

Similar to an earlier question I would like to request a regular expression because I don't have to knowledge to write it myself...

Could I please get examples of the following, as regular expressions

Values must equal:

```
nn-nn-nnnn
nn/nn/nnnn
```

Where n = an integer.

Comment: Date handling cannot reliably be implemented or handled solely using a regular expression. Rethink your requirements and then post your attempts in your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) . Tell us the issues you're facing and [what you did to solve it](http://whathaveyoutried.com). StackOverflow isn't the high school nerd that will do your work for you.

Comment: As @PenguinCoder already wrote: what are you trying to do? Why must some datetime format equal another? Both could be inserted to the constructor of `DateTime` and you'll get a date out of it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY this one

[0-9-]{2}(/|-)[0-9]{2}(/|-)[0-9]{4}

i check this in 
http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

and its working fine

Answer (score 1):

I prefer forcing users to input their date data in standard form (ISO 8601).

I use this for year-month-date (with optional separators: /, -). Please note that this could still lead to error when inserting values into database's `date` column as it allows the month and day to be for example 99.

```
^(\d{4})[/|-]?(\d{2})[/|-]?(\d{2})$
```

If you're not happy with ISO 8601, you can juggle the elements in the regex to for example month-day-year. But then you'll face the problem which Kolink mentioned. Does the inputted value really mean month-day-year or day-month-year? (This isn't necessarily an issue if you use separate form input fields for day and month.)

Answer (score 0):

"Integer" in regex is `\d`, for a certain number you can quantify with `{x}`, x being the number you want. For options of what symbol is allowed, use `[...]` to list the valid characters. Keep in mind that `-` has a special meaning there unless it is the first or last character inside the brackets. The rest is up to you, but...

How do you know what 04-03-2012 actually means? April 3rd, or March 4th?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

> Checks the validity of the date formed by the arguments. A date is
>   considered valid if each parameter is properly defined.